# express.router throws 404 if routes mentioned in separate file

Tags: node.js, express

I am having trouble and have already spent quite a time to figure out the cause but to no avail. I have researched and feel like I am doing right but obviously I missing out something.

Here is my app.js:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

app.use(express.static('./server/static/'));
app.use(express.static('./client/dist/'));

// tell the app to parse HTTP body messages
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)

//routes
var authRoutes = require('./server/routes/auth');
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:3000);
});
```

And here is the separate auth (routes file):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
   console.log("im in");
});

module.exports = router;
```

After running this, I get 404 response:
POST http://localhost:3000/signup 404 (Not Found)

If I put the routes in app.js file, I get the desired output. Can someone please help me figure out what is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://localhost:3000/auth/signup

`app.use('/auth', authRoutes);` exposes the `authRoutes` on paths starting with `/auth`.

Comment: Yes, that's it :) Thanks a lot @Kryten. Now everything makes sense. The docs and all.